# webview crashs in 4.1.2 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad parameter

Tags: android, webview

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad parameter

  at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(URLEncodedUtils.java:139)

  at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(URLEncodedUtils.java:76)
atandroid.webkit.AccessibilityInjector.getAxsUrlParameterValue(AccessibilityInjector.java:404)
            at android.webkit.AccessibilityInjector.shouldInjectJavaScript(AccessibilityInjector.java:323)
            at android.webkit.AccessibilityInjector.onPageFinished(AccessibilityInjector.java:282)
            at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.onPageFinished(WebViewClassic.java:4259)
            at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:325)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your code here to get help!

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been tracked as https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35100

It's a bug of android 4.1.2.

Quote:
"
Fixed in an internal build, to be released in the next major release.
"